# ZMQ publisher server with NodeJS subscriber

Tags: c++, node.js, zeromq

What I am trying to do is to have a C++ ZeroMQ server with publisher role and connect NodeJS subscriber clients.

I was able to get nodeJS server + nodejs client examples working, but I am not able to connect it using C++.

C++ code:

```
#include "zmq.hpp"

//  Convert string to 0MQ string and send to socket
auto s_send(zmq::socket_t & socket, const std::string & string) {    
    zmq::message_t message(string.size());
    memcpy(message.data(), string.data(), string.size());

    return socket.send(message, zmq::send_flags::none); 
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 

    zmq::context_t ctx(1);
    zmq::socket_t sock(ctx, ZMQ_PUB);
    sock.bind("tcp://*:5555");

    Sleep(1000);

    while (true) { 
        s_send(sock, "Hello from the publisher.");
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

NodeJS code:

```
var zmq = require('zeromq');
var sock = zmq.socket('sub');

sock.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5555");
console.log("Subscriber connected to port 5555");

sock.on('message', function(msg){
    console.log('work: %s', msg.toString());
});
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Is there any tutorial on interconnecting ZeroMQ from different languages? I was only able to find examples that use the same technologies on both side of the communication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Q** : *Any ideas what I am doing wrong?*

ZeroMQ **`SUB`**-archetype receives nothing, unless it gets explicitly subscribed to some "*Topic*" ( ""-being a legal one for "everything" ) or it gets set a mirrored-logic of such Topic-filtering configuration on both **`PUB`**-side and **`SUB`**-side, given which a **`ZMQ_INVERT_MATCHING`**-flag self-explains how such subscriptions would start to work.

> *...was able to get nodeJS server + nodejs client examples working*   <sub>*... no chance ... no no 
> kein moeglichkeit - nein nein ...*</sub>

*Tip:* your code does neither one of the must-have subscription settings. **`SUB`**-archetype default state is subscribed to nothing, literally, so the code was not able to get (it) working.

---

> **Q** : *but I am not able to connect it using C++*

Well, before one claims a problem with C++ / API, better do test and document all such potential error-state(s):

MCVE-formulated problem must be re-test-able, otherwise the problem does not exist in Stack Overflow.

ZeroMQ has well crafted error-reporting tools, so in each step, one may read the error-state and report it as per receiving detailed reason for arriving into any kind of defined error-states: `{ EINVAL | ETERM | ENOTSOCK | EINTR | ... }` as defined in ZeroMQ sources ( and well documented in the ZeroMQ API documentation, version by version ).

Comment: I don't get the german stuff in the subscript but anyway... Subscribing the client to "" indeed helps. What remains is how to send messages on a specific topic on the C++ side. The C++ API doesn't seem to handle topics at all. By chance I found out that I can prepend topic info by using `zmq::send_flags::sndmore` flag. Hm...

Comment: **Topic** is since ever in the ZeroMQ API nothing else but a plain, left-to-right byte-level segment (substring) of the message-payload. Multipart-messages ( using ::sndmore ) are a different kind of abstraction, where messages indeed can have multiple-parts, yet the Topic-filter evaluation automation is hidden from the user-level code inside the Context()-instance, so Topic-filter byte-mask(s) are managed there, left-to-right, byte-wise, as per each active Topic-filter list item :o) stay tuned Jan, *no more german* Apropos, how went the claimed nodeJS server/client example w/o a subscribe?

Comment: But that's what the official C++ publisher [example](http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp:psenvpub) does. It sends the topic string via sndmore flag. If I somehow don't get it right, how am I to send a message on a specific topic from C++ publisher then? Thanks...

Comment: PUB-side example without a SUB-side counterparty is meaningless. The ZeroMQ API is clear and sound on how the Topic-filter works. Any wrapper, the more any wrapper-specific example either meets the ZeroMQ API or not. Send a plain string, as explained above and if that meets the ZeroMQ API rules ( having at least one Topic (string) actively subscribed to ) it will get .recv()-ed on the SUB-side. If not, the problem is not in Topic-filtering and due error-detection + error-handling (as noted above) is due to isolate the root-cause of the problem. It is an elementary professional duty to meet API